# Matching "Not a Word" in URL?

Tags: regex, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to catch:

```
http://anydomain/MYDIR/filename.aspx
```

but ***NOT***

```
http://anydomain/subdir/MYDIR/filename.aspx
```

(essentially, the rule is to capture the first, and redirect to the second -- I've moved the files - and anyone bookmarking the old, I want them whisked away to the new).

Everything I've done is capturing both, and generates a fun redirect loop.  Fun as in GRR, not fun as in YAY. Admittedly, I'm terrible at RegEx beyond the basics, for the 2 times a decade I need it, and have promptly forgotten everything. The closest I've gotten is something like this:

```
^.*!NEWDIR\/MYDIR\/filename\.aspx$
```

but it doesn't seem to validate.   I believe it's my "grouping" of `NEWDIR` in the regex, is it thinking I'm only not'ing the N and `EWDIR` is supposed to be there?  How do I get it to "*not*" `NEWDIR` entirely?

Comment: Would this work?   `^.*\/.*[^l].\/MRF\/transfer_discrepant\.aspx$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

`^.*(?<!NEWDIR)\/MYDIR\/filename\.aspx$`

This is using *negative lookbehind*. Here the goal is to math a string that is not proceeded by another string.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/mD7jT4/1) is a working example. For details on *lookbehind* check this [page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).